# Input fields in signup is not editable after I signout but is editable after refresh in angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

My input fields are not editable when I signout . But it gest editable once I refresh . This issue is coming after chrome latest update.

Comment: Please provide the template html and controller script in question. List any other plugins that may also be relevant.